# Woocommerce WP allimport

Tags: woocommerce, wpallimport

I'm using WPallimport to import some products into WooCommerce with xml.
What i want to do is look at the "RetailPrice" of xml and if is smaller than e.g 20€ and "Availability=0" then "Allow Backorders?" is "No" else "Yes"

```
[IF({RetailPrice[1][.>"20,00"]AND{Availability[1][.="0"])][THEN][ΝΟ][ELSE][ΥΕΣ][ENDIF]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a custom PHP function that returns the appropriate value for the backorder field and call it from the backorder text field in the import wizard, something like this:

```
[figure_out_backorder_status({RetailPrice[1]}, Availability[1])]
```

You would add something like this to the Function Editor on the Edit Import page:

```
function figure_out_backorder_status( $price, $availability ) {
  // your logic:
  return 'Yes';
}
```

Documentation:

https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/developers/custom-code/inline-php/